# AWS: VPC Peering between VPC's over multiple AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have two VPC's A (10.0.0.0/16) and B (172.31.0.0/16). A comprises of instances over `eu-central-1a` and B comprises of instances over `eu-central-1b`.

Now to enable communications between the two networks, I added a VPC peering between `VPC-A` and `VPC-B`.

Next, I set up the routes in `VPC-B` as:
Destination: 10.0.0.0/16
Target: `<vpc_peering_id>`

And in `VPC-A` as:
Destination: 172.31.0.0/16
Target: `<vpc_peering_id>`

Security group setting for the target RDS Instance in `VPC-B`
Inbound All Traffic All ports CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16

Security group settings for source instances in `VPC-A`:
Outbound: All Traffic All Ports CIDR: 0.0.0.0/0

But then again, I still cannot make any connections from `VPC-A` to `VPC-B`.

I've also checked the security group settings for all instances belonging to `VPC-A`: All outbound traffic is allowed.
And in `VPC-B`: All incoming traffic from `10.0.0.0/16` is allowed on port `3306`.

What's going on here?

Comment: Is the VPC peering connection still in pending-acceptance state?

Comment: No. I accepted it right after I created it.

Comment: maybe another silly question, but as everything sounds ok within the steps you achieved.... are you sure that your RDS is listening on port 3306? can you access this database from an instance spawned within VPC B?

Comment: Yeah. It is listening on `3306` and can be reached at that port from another instance within the same VPC.

Comment: mmh... what error do you get: -1- when you ping your database from an instance -2- when using a ping over tcp (nc -zvv <database> 3306) ?

Comment: Pings get blocked by default, I guess. My errors are timeouts for `telnet db.endpoint 3306` from VPC-A.

Comment: You said you checked your SG's, did you also check your route tables?

Comment: Check the route tables for each subnet. It's likely they weren't updated. Peering doesn't specifically care about subnets or AZs so that shouldn't affect the connection. If the routes are fine it's probably an ACL or SG issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the confirmation, You need to associate the particular subnets in routing table also which you want to route through . Hope you did that. That's the only possibility left in this scenario.